# How do you reference a variable within another variable in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, for-loop

I am trying to do something which I thought would be fairly simple but not having any joy.

If I run the following, it successfully pulls the region (reg) from an array called PORT330 and checks to see it contains the value of $i. For example, it could be checking to see if "Europe London" contains the word "London". Here is what works:

```
if [[ ${PORT330[reg]} == *"$i"* ]] ; then 
   echo 302 is in $i ; 
fi
```

However, I actually have a list of Port array's to check so it may be PORT330, PORT550 and so on. I want to be able to substitute the port number with a variable but then call it within a variable. Here is what I am trying to do:

This works:

```
for portid in ${portids[@]} ; do 
  for i in ${regions[@]} ; do 
    if [[ ${PORT330[reg]} == *"$i"* ]] ; then 
      echo $portid is in $i ; 
    fi  ;
  done ; 
done
```

However this doesn't work:

```
for portid in ${portids[@]} ; do 
  for i in ${regions[@]} ; do 
    if [[ ${PORT$portid[reg]} == *"$i"* ]] ; then 
      echo $portid is in $i ; 
    fi  ; 
  done ; 
done
```

It throws this error:

```
-su: ${PORT$portid[reg]}: bad substitution
```

Any pointers as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In BASH variable expansion there is an option to have indirection via the `${!name}` and `${!name[index]}` schemes

```
for portid in ${portids[@]} ; do 
   for i in ${regions[@]} ; do 
      arr=PORT$portid
      if [[ ${!arr[reg]} == *"$i"* ]] ; then 
          echo $portid is in $i ; 
      fi  ; 
    done ; 
done
```

Here is a complete example

```
PORT330[reg]=a ; 
PORT550[reg]=b ; 
for portid in 330 550 ; do 
   for i in a b ; 
       do arr=PORT$portid ; 
       if [[ ${!arr[reg]} == *"$i"* ]] ; then 
           echo $portid is in $i ; 
       fi  ; 
   done ; 
done
```

Produces

```
330 is in a
550 is in b
```

Another example

```
:~> portids=(330 350 )
:~> echo ${portids[@]}
330 350
:~> PORT350[reg]=London
:~> PORT330[reg]=Berlin
:~> for portid in ${portids[@]} ; do arr=PORT$portid ; echo ${!arr[reg]} ; done
Berlin
London
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that but it doesn't work for me. It seems as though ${!arr[reg]} is not producing anything.                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                              
root@raynard-batmobile:~# echo $arr
echo $arr
PORT330
root@raynard-batmobile:~# echo ${!arr[reg]}
echo ${!arr[reg]

Comment: @user3507094 added a complete example. Please compare that with what you've got.

Comment: I am still unable to get it to work. This is me echoing the port ids:                                                                                root@raynard-batmobile:~# echo ${portids[@]}
296 302 303 311 312 313 325 326 328 334 335 336 341 342 343 344 345 346 347 348 349 350 351 354 355 357 358 359 360 361 362 363 364 365 366 367 368 369 370 371 372 373 374 375 376 377 329 330

Comment: Then this is me echoing one of the arrays: root@raynard-batmobile:~# echo ${PORT350[reg]}
XYZEurope London

Comment: When I run this, I get lots of lines of nothing. root@raynard-batmobile:~# for portid in ${portids[@]} ; do arr=PORT$portid ; echo ${!arr[reg]} ; done

Comment: @user3507094 I have added another example at the end of the post. Can you reproduce it?